# Applying a general result to a specific case: if $e^a = 1$, then $a = 2in\pi$

Tags: complex-numbers

In a (Partial Differential Equations / Laplace Equation) , I try to solving a problem of Laplace eq. by using separation of variables method.

I usually using the rule : if $e^{2 \sqrt{k} b} = 1$, then I have: $2\sqrt{k} b = 2ni\pi$.

Now in my problem I have : $e^{2 \sqrt{k}\pi} = 1$
Can I use the same rule which lead to cancel the $\pi$ ?

Comment: I've edited your question to make the formatting look fancy: you might want to click "edit" on it to see how it works.

Comment: Do you mean $$e^{2\sqrt{k}b}=1$$?

Comment: thanx and yes I mean I have $e^{2 \sqrt{k} b} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed: the result that you quote (after correcting the missing/surplus $2$) is true for all complex values of $b$, and so, if $e^{2\sqrt{k}\pi} = 1$, then you have $2\sqrt{k}\pi = 2ni\pi$, and hence $\sqrt{k} = ni$, for some integer $n$.

Comment: Here's how I'm interpretting the question: the asker is aware of the general fact that if $e^a = 1$, then $a = 2ni\pi$, for some integer $n$. The asker wishes to know if they can apply this fact to the case where $a = 2\sqrt{k}\pi$, and has made some typos in writing their formula (probably due to the almost-unreadable format in which they were originally written, prior to my correcting them to LaTeX).

Comment: @DietrichBurde The question does, however. Are you really surprised that the question has a poor title?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The title is essentially gibberish. There's nothing to understand. In fact, I'll go and fix it now.

Comment: Thanx I got it and thanx again for fixixng the title.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Euler's formula for complex numbers

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

We know that $\cos(2n\pi)=1, \sin(2n\pi)=0$, for $n\in \Bbb Z$ so:

$$n\in \Bbb Z \implies e^{2ni\pi}=1$$

You have, therefore, in the first part of your question:

$$2b\sqrt k =2ni\pi\to b\sqrt k=ni\pi\to k=-(\frac{n\pi}{b})^2$$

This CAN be applied to part b as well:

$$2\pi\sqrt k=2ni\pi\to\sqrt k=ni\to k=-n^2$$

Comment: Thanx for your detail I got it.